# Core plot : bars disappears when switching app to background and then to foreground while drawing a bar graph

Tags: iphone, ios8, core-graphics, core-plot

My bar graph disappears when I switch my app to background and then again comes back to foreground.

It's like shown below :

```
|||        ||   ||
```

So in the above picture I have gaps, that means when my app is in background core plot does not draw bar graph. Is it a limitation of core plot?

My main task is to draw one bar per second and I have done this, but it's not working while in background. Is there some other alternate option by which I can achieve this?

Here is what I tried:

I made my graph object nil and then tried it reloading when app again comes back to foreground. But it didn't work.

```
 -(void)redrawGraphWhenApplicationEntersForeground
 {
   NSLog(@"reload graph");
   NSLog(@"all plots : %@ , %@", [self.graph allPlots], plotArray);
   DDLogInfo(@"relaod graph when entered in Foreground ");

//    [self.data removeAllObjects];
//Create graph and set it as host view's graph
self.graph = nil;
[self.graph reloadDataIfNeeded];
}`
```

Here is my full code :

// Update is called by a timer ( of 10 second) , so that each second this method will be called and it will draw a bar.

```
- (void)update:(id)data1 withState:(NSInteger) type
{
    switch (type) {
        case ZAP_UPDATE:
            if(curLinkType == DOWNLINK)
            {
                [self drawDownlinkGrpah];
                
            }else if(curLinkType == UPLINK)
            {
                [self drawUplinkGrpah];
            }
            
            [gauge setValue:speedValue];
            
            break;
        case ZAP_DONE:
            [self displayDone:type speedBps:speedBps pktLoss:pktLoss srcdst:[zap destinationAddress]];
            
            onTap = false;
            runningTime=0;
            if(gauge != nil){
                [gauge setValue:0];
            }
        {
            NSArray *parameter = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: speed, unit, nil];
            [self performSelector:@selector(stopGauge:) withObject:parameter afterDelay:0.2];
        }
            

    }
}
    
- (void)drawDownlinkGrpah {
    
    DownlinCount++;
    
    self.downlinkdata = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    double position = DownlinCount*((4*10)/(double)durationval);
    NSDictionary *bar = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:position],BAR_POSITION,
                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:speedBarValue],BAR_HEIGHT,
                         [UIColor orangeColor],COLOR,
                         nil];
    [self.downlinkdata addObject:bar];
    
    self.data = self.downlinkdata;
    [self generateBarPlotForDownlink:YES];
    
}


- (void)drawUplinkGrpah {
    UplinkCount++;
    self.uplinkdata = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    double position = UplinkCount*((4*10)/(double)durationval);
    NSDictionary *bar = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:position],BAR_POSITION,
                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:speedBarValue],BAR_HEIGHT,
                         [UIColor orangeColor],COLOR,
                         nil];
    [self.uplinkdata addObject:bar];
    self.data = self.uplinkdata;
    [self generateBarPlotForDownlink:NO];
    
}

- (NSInteger)getBarposition:(NSInteger)samplesize {
    
    return (4*10)/samplesize;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)resetGraph:(UIImageView*) imageview {
    for(UIView *view in imageview.subviews)
        
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"graph_container"]];
}


#pragma mark -
-(void)appGoesinBackground
{
//    NSLog(@"make nil graph");
//    DDLogInfo(@"remove graph when entered in background ");
//    
    self.graph = nil;
//    [self.data removeAllObjects];
    [plotArray removeAllObjects]; // remove all data before entering to background
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(redrawGraphWhenApplicationEntersForeground)
                                                 name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object: nil];
}

// redraw graph ..
-(void)redrawGraphWhenApplicationEntersForeground
{
    
    NSLog(@"reload graph");
    NSLog(@"all plots : %@ , %@", [self.graph allPlots], plotArray);
    
    DDLogInfo(@"relaod graph when entered in Foreground ");
    
//    [self.data removeAllObjects];
    //Create graph and set it as host view's graph
//    self.graph = nil;
//    
    for (CPTBarPlot *p in plotArray) {
//        [self.graph addPlot:p];
        [p reloadData];
    }
    
}


#pragma mark - generate bar plot
- (void)generateBarPlotForDownlink:(BOOL)enabled
{
    NSLog(@"generateBarPlotForDownlink >>>>>>");
    //Create host view
    
    self.hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-35, -20, 128, 73)];
    
    //Create graph and set it as host view's graph
    self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.downlinkImageView.frame];
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    
    [self.hostingView setHostedGraph:self.graph];
    
    if(enabled) // for downlink graph ..
    {
        self.downlinkImageView.image=nil;
        [self.downlinkImageView addSubview:self.hostingView];
    }
    else{ // for uplink graph ..
        self.uplinkImageView.image=nil;
        [self.uplinkImageView addSubview:self.hostingView];
    }
    
    // Create bar plot and add it to the graph
    CPTBarPlot *plot = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init] ;
    plot.dataSource = self;
    plot.delegate = self;
    
    
    //set axes ranges
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:
                        CPTDecimalFromFloat(AXIS_START)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat((AXIS_END - AXIS_START)+1)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:
                        CPTDecimalFromFloat(AXIS_START)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(maxYRange)];
    
    
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.0f);
    axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.0f);
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 1.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 1.0f;
    
    axisSet.hidden=YES;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy=CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy=CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    
    float barwidht = (2*10.0)/(float)durationval;
    
    

    NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", barwidht];
    plot.barWidth = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:inStr] // Need to change according sample  // 1.5 for 10 , 0.75 for 20
                     decimalValue];
    plot.barOffset = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5.0"]
                      decimalValue];
    plot.barCornerRadius = 0.0;
    
    // Remove bar outlines
    CPTMutableLineStyle *borderLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    borderLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    plot.lineStyle = borderLineStyle;
    
    plot.identifier = @"chocoplot";
    
    
    [self.graph addPlot:plot];
    

    
    // Add plot to array in case if app is moved to background state ..
    [plotArray addObject:plot];
    
    NSLog(@"plot  : %@",plot);

    NSLog(@"plot added ..%lu", (unsigned long)plotArray.count );
    
}



-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"chocoplot"] )
        return [self.data count];
    
    return 0;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"chocoplot"] )
    {
        NSDictionary *bar = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
        
        if(fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation)
            return [bar valueForKey:BAR_POSITION];
        else if(fieldEnum ==CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip)
            return [bar valueForKey:BAR_HEIGHT];
    }
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
}

-(CPTFill *)barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot
                  recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ( [barPlot.identifier isEqual:@"chocoplot"] )
    {
        NSDictionary *bar = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
        CPTGradient *gradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:[CPTColor redColor]
                                                            endingColor:[bar valueForKey:@"COLOR"]
                                                      beginningPosition:0.0 endingPosition:0.6 ];
        [gradient setGradientType:CPTGradientTypeAxial];
        [gradient setAngle:320.0];
        
        CPTFill *fill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:gradient];
        
        return fill;
        
    }
    return [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
    
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The call to `reloadDataIfNeeded` has no effect since you've already set the graph to `nil`.

Comment: Is the whole graph released when the app goes into the background, or is this just a drawing problem?

Comment: yes for the time being i am releasing graph object .. I have also tried not to release it .. but I have applied every possible way to resolve this issue . And i am help less here ..  Is this this an iOS issue ??? does iOS sdk updates UI when in background ?? does core plot has this feature so that it can also draw graphs while in background or any other alternative ?? A lots of questions are there in my mind .. I am really stuck here man ,..

Comment: and I have tried using reloadData too..

Comment: What about the hosting view? Make sure that it doesn't go away when the app goes into the background. Is the screenshot in the question the before or after view? Which part of that is drawn by Core Plot? Just the bars?

Comment: yes just the bars ... I am posting code too in the question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me :

```
- (void)drawDownlinkGrpah {

    NSLog(@"drawDownlinkGrpah CAlled");

    DownlinCount++;

    double position = DownlinCount*((4*10)/(double)durationval);
    NSDictionary *bar = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:position],BAR_POSITION,
                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:speedBarValue],BAR_HEIGHT,
                         [UIColor orangeColor],COLOR,
                         nil];
    [self.downlinkdata addObject:bar];

    self.data = self.downlinkdata;
    [self generateBarPlotForDownlink:YES];

}

#pragma mark - generate bar
- (void)generateBarPlotForDownlink:(BOOL)enabled
{
    if(enabled)
    {
        self.downlinkImageView.image=nil;
        if(![self.hostingView  isDescendantOfView:self.downlinkImageView])
        {
            // Configure hosting view so that it appears from fresh ..
            [self configureGraph];
            [self.downlinkImageView addSubview:self.hostingView];

            NSLog(@"hosting view added in downlink view ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.uplinkImageView.image=nil;
        // if hosting view is not in uplink view
        if(![self.hostingView  isDescendantOfView:self.uplinkImageView])
        {
            // Configure hosting view so that it appears from fresh ..
            [self configureGraph];
            [self.uplinkImageView addSubview:self.hostingView];

            NSLog(@"hosting view added in uplink view ");

        }
    }

    //set axes ranges
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:
                        CPTDecimalFromFloat(AXIS_START)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat((AXIS_END - AXIS_START)+1)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:
                        CPTDecimalFromFloat(AXIS_START)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(maxYRange)];


    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.0f);
    axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.0f);
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 1.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 1.0f;

    axisSet.hidden=YES;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy=CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy=CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

    // Create bar plot and add it to the graph
    NSLog(@"plot created %ld", (long)durationval);
    CPTBarPlot *plot = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init] ;
    plot.dataSource = self;
    plot.delegate = self;

    float barwidht = (2*10.0)/(float)durationval;
    NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", barwidht]; //CPTDecimalFromDouble(2.0);

    plot.barWidth = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:inStr]
                     decimalValue];// Need to change according sample  // 1.5 for 10 , 0.75 for 20

    plot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(barwidht);

    plot.barOffset = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5.0"]
                      decimalValue];
    plot.barCornerRadius = 0.0;

    // Remove bar outlines
    CPTMutableLineStyle *borderLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    borderLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    plot.lineStyle = borderLineStyle;

    plot.identifier = @"chocoplot";
    [self.graph addPlot:plot];

}

#pragma mark - core plot data source and delegate methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"chocoplot"] )
        return [self.data count];

    return 0;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"chocoplot"] )
    {
        NSDictionary *bar = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];

        if(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX)
            return [bar valueForKey:BAR_POSITION];
        else if(fieldEnum ==CPTScatterPlotFieldY)
            return [bar valueForKey:BAR_HEIGHT];
    }
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
}
```

`drawDownlinkGraph` method would be called each second using a timer and it will call `generateBarPlotForDownlink:` Method every second . And bar will be drawn each second on a real time basis even if APP is in background.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a new graph every time you get new plot data. Just add the new point to the `data` array and call `-reloadData` on the plot.

When the app goes into the background, just clear your `data` array and call `-reloadData` on the plot. It will reload the empty data and display the graph when the app comes back to the foreground. There's no reason to set `self.graph` to `nil` unless you remove the graph from the hosting view and you want it to go away. From what I can see in the posted code, the graph is still in the hosting view, but you've lost your reference to it, making any updates you make when the app comes to the foreground ineffective.

Comment: i have done the same .. just created only once instance of hosting view and graph .. but this time graph disappeared. Also in my code .. i am adding plots to graph each second after timer fires.. My main task is to draw one bar per second . Can you suggest me some other alternate option or a sample code by which i can achieve this .. ???

Comment: Also if i will clear data array then how graph will get values again when it will resume in foreground ?? in your realtime data example ... it stops the timer i think and resume the graph from the same location where it left ..

Comment: Do you want to clear the plot data when the app goes to the background, or should it resume with the same data it had before? Plots cache their data, so it will display the old data the next time it is drawn unless you tell it new data is available with `-reloadData`. The `-appGoesinBackground` method doesn't need to do anything with the graph or plots. `-redrawGraphWhenApplicationEntersForeground` can be simply `[self.graph reloadData];`.

Comment: Hi Eric: Thanks for your support .. really appreciate it .. I am finally able to draw graph even if its in backgrond and when it comes to foreground it keeps drawing plots .. lets say graph has drawn 5 bar when it was taken to back ground and when it is taken again to foreground after 10 seconds bar drawns are 15 . So thats i wanted . Now I have a diffrent issue which is I think is the feature of core plot , Please correct me if I am wrong : The width of the bars are uneven when numbers of bars to be drawn are increased . Is it a feature of core plot ?

Comment: By default, the `barWidth` is given as a fraction of the distance between adjacent bar locations. Set `barWidthsAreInViewCoordinates` to `YES` if you'd rather specify the width in points. That will keep the width constant if the size of the graph and/or the plot range changes.